# ERROR: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'name' of null

Tags: reactjs, firebase, fileupload, storage

estoy subiendo una imagen a Firebase Storage mediante fileUpload. La imagen carga correctamente y se sube correctamente pero al momento de terminar de cargar me aparece el siguiente error, alguna solución? y la funcion que utilizo para cargar tiene async await, help.

ADJUNTO EL CÓGIDO:

```
const handleUploadSuccess = async nombre => {
    guardarProgreso(100);
    guardarSubiendo(false);

    //Almacenar la URL
    const url = await firebase
                .storage
                .ref("servicios")
                .child(nombre)
                .getDownloadURL();

    console.log(url);
    guardarUrlimagen(url);
}
```

Comment: no encuentro en el código donde este la propiedad name, podrias actualizar el codigo ?

Answer (score 0):

Que onda, buen día.

Yo tuve exactamente el mismo problema.
Y al revisar encontré que dentro de la librería (no en mi codigo) estaba tratando de obtener la propiedad name de los metadata, los cuales estaban con null.

Parece que es un problema con las ultimas versiones del firebase y el react-firebase-file-uploader... al 08 de enero de 2020 yo estaba usando estas: 
"**firebase**": "^8.2.1",
"**firebase-admin**": "^9.4.2",
"**react-firebase-file-uploader**": "^2.4.3"

Y NO encontré una solución compatible con esas versiones (Si la encuentras, ponla, por favor)

Asi que lo que hice fue usar versiones anteriores:

"**firebase**": "^7.6.1",
"**firebase-admin**": "^8.9.0",
"**react-firebase-file-uploader**": "^2.4.3"

Y usando esas versiones ya no me dio ningún problema.

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.